# Firefox Aurora update release notes?

Tags: firefox, updates

I use Aurora and want to know where I can find release notes for each update to Aurora.

Answer (score 5):

On Aurora's wiki page:

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/Aurora

there seems to be a link to the most recent commit messages :

[image]

The Meeting Notes also offer added information on each "release."

They also have release notes on the mozilla blog, [here](http://blog.mozilla.com/futurereleases/2011/07/07/firefoxaurora7/).

**So in some way the ["Future of Firefox" blog](http://blog.mozilla.com/futurereleases/category/aurora/) is what you're looking for.**

Comment: Great answer - there really isn't a release notes at the aurora stage, since it's basically a development preview version. Aurora is basically a soft-freeze - code needs special approval to get added after the merge point, and strings are already frozen to give translators a full 12 weeks to work on each release. It's not until beta that the shape of the code is final enough to start thinking about release notes - the code freeze standards there are basically to only allow fixes to be committed for unshipped bugs, bugs that would trigger a chemspill, or things of comparable urgency.